# How to create this using Bootstrap and javascript

Tags: calculator, bmi

[BMI calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga9gK.png)

How to create this using Bootstrap and javascript (Above i attached an image )
I am a beginner developer I am trying to create a BMI calculator using Bootstrap and Javascript but am not able to write code please help me

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.